# Transparent Column header in MFC CListCtrl

Tags: mfc, header, transparent, clistctrl

My requirement is to create a transparent list control in MFC dialog based application.
I created the list control with `LVS_EX_TRANSPARENTBKGND` extended style property.
I could make the list control items transparent by overriding `DrawItem()`.

But how I can i make the column headers transparent?

Comment: Haven't tried this, but you may have to set the [header control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775239.aspx)'s extended window style to include `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT`, and subclass it to prevent rendering its background. Although I don't know, whether the header control is actually inside the list view's client area (in which case it might work), or the non-client area (in which case it probably won't).

Comment: Is WS_EX_TRANSPARENT works for header ctrl?  I tried by subclassing the headerCtrl. But the default background set is black. So not bale to make it transparent. For list control there is a style, WS_EX_TRANSPARENT, for List Control, which make it transparent.Bit ik.